# Why does Snowflake variable binding in query throw error with table name but not integer?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-injection, string-interpolation

I am following the [Snowflake Python Connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#binding-data) docs for variable binding to avoid SQL injection. I successfully set up a db connection with the following dict of credentials:

```
import snowflake.connector

CONN = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user=snowflake_creds['user'],
    password=snowflake_creds['password'],
    account=snowflake_creds['account'],
    warehouse=snowflake_creds["warehouse"],
    database=snowflake_creds['database'],
    schema=snowflake_creds['schema'],
)
cur = CONN.cursor(snowflake.connector.DictCursor)
```

The following block works fine and I get back query results, hard-coding the table name and using the standard `format` binding:

```
command = ("SELECT * FROM TEST_INPUT_TABLE WHERE batch_id = %s")
bind_params = (2)
results = cur.execute(command % bind_params).fetchall()
```

Similarly, this block works fine, using the `pyformat` binding:

```
command = ("SELECT * FROM TEST_INPUT_TABLE WHERE batch_id = %(id)s")
bind_params = {"id": 2}
results = cur.execute(command, bind_params).fetchall()
```

But the following two blocks both result in a `ProgrammingError` (pasted below the second block):

```
command = ("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE batch_id = %s")
bind_params = ("TEST_INPUT_TABLE", 2)
results = cur.execute(command, bind_params).fetchall()


command = ("SELECT * FROM %(tablename)s WHERE batch_id = %(id)s")
bind_params = {
    "tablename": "TEST_INPUT_TABLE",
    "id": 2
    }
results = cur.execute(command, bind_params).fetchall()


    ProgrammingError: 001011 (42601): SQL compilation error:
    invalid URL prefix found in: 'TEST_INPUT_TABLE'
```

Is there some difference between how strings and ints get interpolated? I would
not think it would make a difference but that is all I can think of. Am I
missing something simple here? I don't want to have to choose between hard-coding the table name and putting the system at risk of SQL injection. Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be wrapping your bind variables with an `INDENTIFER()` function when they reference an object, rather than a string literal.  For example:

```
command = ("SELECT * FROM IDENTIFIER(%(tablename)s) WHERE batch_id = %(id)s")
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html

Give that a try.

Comment: Thank you. I did not (but probably should have) included the fully qualified name that I was going for, which is `<database>.<schema>.<tablename>` ... now I'm trying `...IDENTIFIER(%(database)s.%(schema)s.%(tablename)s)...` and various variations on this, but nothing works and I get `ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error: syntax error....unexpected '.'.`   Is there a way to use the fully qualified name with the bindings? The docs indicate yes, but there are no examples with the `pyformat` binding I'm using.

Comment: Try concatenating the database, schema, and tablename into a single variable and using that inside the IDENTIFIER function.  I think that is how I've done this in the past.

Comment: Ah, the concatenation works perfectly. Thank you!